# Add 28 to last 2 digit of date and replace the order

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have a number such as this : 840106

I need to do the following :

1. Change the number to date add - and flip the number : 06-01-84
2. add 28 to the last 2 digit that the date will be : 06-01-12

84 + 16 = 00 + 12 = 12

number is always changing sometimes it cab be  850617 , but format is always same add - and add 28 last 2 digit.

any ideas how to help me here ?

Comment: You specified 2 RDMS: MySQL and SQLite. Are you using both of them? In MySQL there is a special date type: yyyy-mm-dd. Why are you using this bizarre format?

Comment: I run both of them , I need a solution for both,..

Comment: Why aren't you using Datetime field type for SQLite and Date type for SQL? It's much better, then string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sqlite solution:

```
create table t( c text);

insert into t (c) values(990831);
insert into t (c) values(840106);
insert into t (c) values(800315);
insert into t (c) values(750527);
insert into t (c) values(700923);
insert into t (c) values(620308);

select c, substr(c,5,2) || '-' || substr(c,3,2) || '-' || 
  case when (substr(c,1,2) + 28) < 100 then (substr(c,1,2) + 28) 
       else case when ((substr(c,1,2) + 28) - 100) < 10 then '0' || ((substr(c,1,2) + 28) - 100) 
         else ((substr(c,1,2) + 28) - 100) 
        end
  end
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

For formatting you can use 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

For adding days to the date you should take a look at date_add() function

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD('1998-01-02', INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is the name of the column containing your date:

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(date, %y%m%d), INTERVAL 28 YEAR), %d-%m-%y);
```

What this does is first formats the string into a date, then adds 28 years, then converts back to string with the new format.

SQLite is a lot tricker with this, you'll need to use substrings.

```
substr(date,5) || "-" || substr(date,3,4)  || "-" || CAST(CAST(substr(date,1,2) as integer) + 28 - 100) as text
```

I'm not too experienced with SQLite so the casting may be a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a t-sql solution that you can use and migrate to mysql.

```
declare @myDate as char(8) = '840106';
declare @y as char(2), @m as char(2), @d as char(2);

set @y = LEFT (@myDate, 2);
declare @yi as int = Convert (int, @y);

IF @y between 30 and 99 ----------- pick a cut-off year 
    SET @yi = (28 - (100-@yi));
SET @y = CONVERT(char, @yi)

set @m = SUBSTRING(@myDate, 3, 2);
set @d = SUBSTRING(@myDate, 5, 2);
SET @myDate = @d + '-' + @m + '-' + @y;
PRINT @myDate;
```